# Monitor Processes' Memory Usage

Tags: memory, process, aix, java

We have an IBM P series box running AIX 5.3. This is our application server, whereby our J2EE application is running in Oracle's Applications Server (version 10g r2). At around 11pm till the next day 7am, we have shell scripts running, which executes Java class programs.

Recently, this server has been experiencing some high memory usage, which caused some of the Java class programs throwing "Out of memory" exception .

We normally use NMON to monitor the server's resources, such as CPU, I/O, memory, etc. But because of this OOM issue, we would like to know throughout the day, what are the processes which are running and how much memory each process consumed.

NMON is not able to show this. Even with the "-T" parameter, it only shows the top processes and not all.

Is there any thing we can use to monitor  all the processes' memory?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an AIX expert, but ipcs could help.

**ipsc -bom** will show you active memory segment with their owner and size. It could be enought to determine who consume the memory.

Comment: Is ipcs not only for shared memory?

Comment: @Gaius yes it is.

Comment: I've not heard of ipsc. Tried to google for it and got non-relevant results. Is there a website I can refer to or a wikipedia entry?

Comment: @Alvin IBM Documentation should contain informations. Have a look at http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds3/ipcs.htm

Answer (score 0):

WLM (WorkLoad Manager) do the job, look at:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-Practical_WLM.html
http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg245977.html